# How to fit a 3 D plane Pi on some image pixels using SVD and RANSAC?

Tags: pca, svd, ransac

I am trying to implement a paper: 'Combining multiple depth-based descriptors for hand gesture recognition' by Fabio Dominio, Mauro Donadeo, Pietro Zanuttigh. There is this part attached in the form of an image (Fitting 3D plane Pi using SVD and RANSAC) which I am not able to understand (in terms of purpose) and also the implementation using MATLAB.
![Paper_text]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sIJfcGVgbNYdU_ZA7n_ASIR-A8KX9i7t
![Paper_Figure]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hq8PBtZiVvM5lX0Dt2ysEAh5dHlLIrf6

I have tried to implement the start of it but have no idea how to form the axis as given in the paper (Fig 3). The code I have tried is also given here.

![Hand Gesture]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xz8ajG-Zxc3mHQ9LbuoBh1UQAXMmf0SY

```
plot(hands(:,1),hands(:,2),'o'); % 'hands' are the image pixels of the 
                                 %  hand palm region to be used in fitting
hold on;
modelLeastSquares = polyfit(hands(:,1),hands(:,2),1);
x = [min(hands(:,1)) max(hands(:,1))];
y = modelLeastSquares(1)*x + modelLeastSquares(2);
plot(x,y,'r-')
sampleSize = 2; % number of points to sample per trial
maxDistance = 2; % max allowable distance for inliers

fitLineFcn = @(hands) polyfit(hands(:,1),hands(:,2),1); % fit function 
                                                          using polyfit
evalLineFcn = ...   % distance evaluation function
@(model, hands) sum((hands(:, 2) - polyval(model, hands(:,1))).^2,2);

[modelRANSAC, inlierIdx] = ransac(hands,fitLineFcn,evalLineFcn, ...
sampleSize,maxDistance);

modelInliers = polyfit(hands(inlierIdx,1),hands(inlierIdx,2),1);

inlierPts = hands(inlierIdx,:);
x = [min(inlierPts(:,1)) max(inlierPts(:,1))];
y = modelInliers(1)*x + modelInliers(2); hold on;
plot(x, y, 'g-')
legend('Noisy points','Least squares fit','Robust fit');
hold off
```

![Output]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wVwezBdxX-xREwZs7X2yjkzVZHn9nY0C

What is 3D plane Pi and why and how is it fitting using SVD and RANSAC? The actual aim of the paper in this part is to get the approximate direction of fingers using SVD, RANSAC, and PCA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, somebody, let me know how to fit the 3D Pi plane using RANSAC and get an image of hand as in the above-given picture in that 3D plane.